# Detect Clicks outside QML Window

Tags: qml, qt-quick

How do i detect clicks outside Window {} in QML ?

```
Rectangle {
   id: topLevel

   height: 400; width: 400

   Window {
      id: windowObj

      color: "blue"
      height: 200; width: 200
      onActiveChanged { console.trace(); visible = false; }
   }

   Component.onCompleted: windowObj.visible = true
}
```

Suppose I click on some part of `topLevel` outside `windowObj`.

`onActiveChanged` works on Windows but not on MAC.

```
{Using: QtQuick 2.1, QtQuick.Window 2.1, QML/Qt 5.2.0}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put a MouseArea in your topLevel Rectangle and let the event pass through

```
Rectangle {
   id: topLevel

   MouseArea{
      anchors.fill : topLevel
      propagateComposedEvents : true
      onClicked : console.log("clickoutside");
   }

   Window {
      id: windowObj

      color: "blue"
      height: 200; width: 200
      onActiveChanged { console.trace(); visible = false; }
   }
}
```

Comment: I want to avoid this. I basically want this window as a drop down of my custom combobox. It should close whenever there is any sort of mouse-press outside it - even outside the Application itself, or on the title-bar etc. Then i need to capture all events and see which one should close my `Window {`} etc. Do you know of any other/better way - like `onActiveChanged` works perfectly fine on Windows OS?

Comment: the other way is to add an event handler in the qml container itself like the QtQuick2ApplicationViewer of Qt are whatever the qml is running in. add an eventfilter function and if your conditions for the outside clic match send an event into your qml.